# Python regex get with zero or more occurences within the pattern

Tags: python, regex

I've a working regex that's giving me the results that I want, yet it doesn't contain the safety it needs. (Fool-proof)

Lets say I have a regex that matches parts of a path, something along the lines of:

```
import re
path = "C:/Projects/foo/dev/model/props/furniture/couch/data/fbx"
regex = re.compile("(.+)/dev/model/(.+)/(.+)/data/fbx")
m = regex.search(path)
if m:
    print m.groups()

# ('C:/Projects/foo', 'props/furniture', 'couch')
```

I want to be able to replace the *match any character up till the following part of the regex* with something that will match one or more folders.

Let's say we define a folder for simplicity as word characters (none or more) ending with a slash it would be:

```
[\w]*/
```

And I want to group zero to ten of those, how would I do that?

In my mind I had something like (note that this doesn't work!):

```
# match any number of word characters ending with a slash zero to ten times
([[\w]*/]{0,10})

# match any number of word characters ending with a slash zero to one time
([[\w]*/]?)
```

EDIT:

Based on RedBaron and jamylak's answer I came up with the following:

```
((?:[:\w]+/){0,3})
```

This will group zero to three occurences [:\w] characters ending with a slash '/'. With the ?: at the beginning of the group it's not being send back to the matched groupings. So yet the outer group that combines them is. Therefore we only get the fully grouped result back.

The only issue with this is that I want the last part to also possibly match a file. (So not ending with a slash.) I even prefer to get it back without the trailing slash from the regex, but I could also easily strip that of the end of the result.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. If this is the way to go I'll add it as an answer.

EDIT:

It's related to: [Finding folders back based on a predefined folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531977/finding-folders-back-based-on-a-predefined-folder-structure)

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

Based on all the answers given so far I've come up with a variety of tries, yet they all end up extremely slow in the end.

```
import re
path = "C:/Projects/foo/dev/model/props/furniture/couch/data/fbx"
regex = re.compile(r"""((?:^(?:[\w:]+/?)+)|(?:(?<=/)(?:[\w]+/?)+))/dev/model/""")
print 'search start'
m = regex.search(path)
print 'search done'
if m:
    print 'match', m, m.groups()
else:
    print 'no match'
```

I'm not entirely sure how to speed this up!

Comment: Please show what the desired output is for the example `path`.

Comment: The output as given from the top example code in my question is the wanted output. Yet I want to add more functionality to the matches so I could define it more precisely. So for example match only two to four folders in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` in your regexp will not group the regexp. It is used to specify the character-class.

Maybe this will work-

```
\w*/{0,10}
```

And for grouping just use `()`

```
(\w*/){0,10}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edited question, I think what you want is that 0-3 occurrences of the directory name match and then a file name matches too.

Assuming only alphabets in file names (and an optional upto three character extension)

```
^((?:[:\w]+/){0,3})(\w+(?:\.\w{1,3})?)?$
```

This is very big but can be broken into two parts

This is what you already have

```
((?:[:\w]+/){0,3})
```

And what I add

```
(\w+(?:\.\w{1,3})?)?
```

This is an optional filename at the end. (If it is not optional you can remove the last `?`). The filename itself can either be made up of only alphabtes or also have an extension of maximum 3 characters

Adding `^` and `$` will stop spurous matches

```
>>> pat=re.compile('^((?:[:\w]+/){0,3})(\w+(?:\.\w{1,3})?)?$')
>>> my_str='fwefw/wfwf/wefwf/dde.cdf'
>>> pat.search(my_str).groups()
('fwefw/wfwf/wefwf/', 'dde.cdf')
>>> my_str='fwefw/dde.cdf'
>>> pat.search(my_str).groups()
('fwefw/', 'dde.cdf')
```

Comment: This will group them all seperately. I've done a test (see my edited post above) so that it only returns the fully grouped result as a single group. Is that the way it should be done?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to match a path with some variable parts in the path (see the added link in my question). I've also added a new try but it's becoming extremely slow!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what ypu want here. Can you give some sample inputs/outputs. The more examples, the merrier :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this, which is very slow indeed due to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html),

```
((?:^(?:[\w:]+/?)+)|(?:(?<=/)(?:[\w]+/?)+))/dev/model/
```

try this

```
(^[\w:]+(?:/\w+)*|(?<=/)\w+(?:/\w+)*)/dev/model/
```

or this

```
(^[\w:]+[\w/]*|(?<=/)[\w/]+)/dev/model/
```

---

You might want to consider an approach where you first validate the string using `re.match` and a pattern such as `(\w:)?(/\w+)+$`

Then, when you can expect a certain structure already, you could use a simpler regex to extract the data:

```
/?([^/]*(?:/[^/]+)*)/dev/model/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `[]` inside `[]` like you did here `([[\w]*/]{0,10})`. Instead you wanna use brackets to group.

Try this:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\w*/){0,10}', 'abc/def/ghi/').group()
'abc/def/ghi/'
```

Comment: Awesome. Based on your answer I seem to have found exactly what I needed. ;) I'll post it in a second. Let me know if you see any errors.